# No se muestran algunos datos de la api

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy haciendo maps desde una api dentro de un map, aparentemente la consola muestra todo correctamente pero al llevarlo al html no muestra los datos completos pero tampoco muestra errores en la consola.

```
import axios from "axios";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [events, setEvents] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://www.mocky.io/v2/59f08692310000b4130e9f71").then((res) => {
      setEvents(res.data);
    });
  }, []);

  console.log(events);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="events">
        {events.map((event, i) => (
          <div key={i}>
            <h1 className="event-name text-xl">{event.name}</h1>
            <h2 className="text-xl">{event?.markets.name}</h2>
            {event?.markets.map((market, i) => { 
              <div key={i}>
                <h3 className="text-xl">{market.name} {console.log(market)}</h3>
              </div>
              {market?.selections.map((selection, i)=>{
                <div key={i}>
                  <p>{selection.name} {selection.price} {console.log(selection)}</p>
                </div>
              })}
            })}
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

En la consola se muestra correctamente como debe ser:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPmc5.png
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

y luego solo se muestra lo del primer map:

```html
{events.map((event, i) => (
          <div key={i}>
            <h1 className="event-name text-xl">{event.name}</h1>
```

Comment: Se ve correcto, ¿puedes colocar el componente entero? Solo con el html es dificil encontrar el error.

Comment: Hola alex, el código es demasiado largo, asi que te dejo la foto

Comment: https://imgbox.com/YOpXjaun

Comment: 40 lineas no es mucho, es mejor para leerlo. Por otro lado... veo que en la linea 14 tienes un console.log, ¿te pinta algo? Puedes colocar un console.log de la respuesta del api antes de ejecutar el setEvents

Comment: Lo que pasa es que stack no me deja ponerlo porque dice que es muy largo, soy nuevo por aquí xd
te muestro foto de la consola https://imgbox.com/UXvsooLx y el link de la api http://www.mocky.io/v2/59f08692310000b4130e9f71

Comment: estaba usando tailwind, no se si tenga algo que ver

Comment: No debería de tener nada que ver, para poner el código sigue esta guía: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/how-do-i-create-a-react-stack-snippet-with-jsx-support

Comment: actualicé el código en el post, estoy leyendo la guía mientras tanto

Comment: si puedes enviarme un mensaje al chat te agredecería amigo

Comment: ¿Por qué usas map en vez de forEach? y ¿Qué tipo de archivo es?

Comment: Aprendí a hacerlo con map amigo, es una api en formato json

Comment: En general, es mejor utilizar map() cuando quieras transformar una colección de elementos y devolver una nueva colección como resultado. Si sólo quieres realizar una acción en cada elemento de la colección sin necesidad de transformar los elementos, puedes utilizar forEach(). Escribiré una respuesta para que la puedas usar

Comment: el console.log de todo, me tira la data perfecta y precisa como se necesita, pero por alguna razón solo me muestra el h1 del primer mapeo en el servidor, el resto no nunca me había pasado

Comment: Gracias Alex, efectivamente, eran los paréntesis lo descubrí tambíen, igualmente muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bien tu problema es pequeño en realidad. Cuando usas map y quieres retornar por defecto en tu función de flecha, debes encerrar tu código entre parentesis o simplemente no usar llaves para denotar que eso es directamente lo que vas a retornar, en caso contrario si vas a meter algún tipo de lógica debes usar llaves y definir que es lo que la función va a retornar, en tu caso en particular, usas llaves pero en ningún momento estás retornando tu jsx.

Veo que no tienes ningún tipo de lógica por lo que basta con reemplazar las llaves por parentesis, tu código quedaría algo así:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";


function App() {
  const [events, setEvents] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://www.mocky.io/v2/59f08692310000b4130e9f71").then((res) => {
      setEvents(res.data);
    });
  }, []);

  console.log(events);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {events.map((event, i) => (
          <div key={i}>
            <h1>{event.name}</h1>
            <h2>{event?.markets.name}</h2>
            {event?.markets.map((market, i) => (
              <>
                <div key={i}>
                  <h3>
                    {market.name} {console.log(market)}
                  </h3>
                </div>
                {market?.selections.map((selection, i) => (
                  <div key={i}>
                    <p>
                      {selection.name} {selection.price}{" "}
                      {console.log(selection)}
                    </p>
                  </div>
                ))}
              </>
            ))}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

En caso de que quisieras hacerlo con las llaves porque necesitas meter algun tipo de lógica antes de retornar tu jsx, esta sería la sintaxis:

```js
import axios from "axios";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [events, setEvents] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://www.mocky.io/v2/59f08692310000b4130e9f71").then((res) => {
      setEvents(res.data);
    });
  }, []);

  console.log(events);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {events.map((event, i) => (
          <div key={i}>
            <h1>{event.name}</h1>
            <h2>{event?.markets.name}</h2>
            {event?.markets.map((market, i) => {
              return (
                <>
                  <div key={i}>
                    <h3>
                      {market.name} {console.log(market)}
                    </h3>
                  </div>
                  {market?.selections.map((selection, i) => {
                    return (
                      <div key={i}>
                        <p>
                          {selection.name} {selection.price}{" "}
                          {console.log(selection)}
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    );
                  })}
                </>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: crack amigo, lo descrubí justo al momento de tu respuesta, gracias un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Prueba haciéndolo con un forEach() en vez de Map():

```
import axios from "axios";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [events, setEvents] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://www.mocky.io/v2/59f08692310000b4130e9f71").then((res) => {
      setEvents(res.data);
    });
  }, []);

  console.log(events);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="events">
        {events.forEach((event, i) => {
          const eventElement = (
            <div key={i}>
              <h1 className="event-name text-xl">{event.name}</h1>
              <h2 className="text-xl">{event.markets.name}</h2>
              {event.markets.forEach((market, i) => {
                const marketElement = (
                  <div key={i}>
                    <h3 className="text-xl">{market.name} {console.log(market)}</h3>
                    {market.selections.forEach((selection, i) => {
                      <div key={i}>
                        <p>{selection.name} {selection.price} {console.log(selection)}</p>
                      </div>
                    })}
                  </div>
                );
                eventElement.appendChild(marketElement);
              })}
            </div>
          );
          document.querySelector(".events").appendChild(eventElement);
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Considero que lo optimo seria usar forEach pues lo que necesitas es iterar los elementos del array más no aplicar una función sobre ellos para que retornen otro array (como lo haría la funcion map())

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'eventElement' before initialization jsx:55

Comment: se me dificulta el uso del foreach, porque siempre para el consumo de apis lo aprendí con .map() y hasta ahora no me había dado problema

Comment: Curioso que no se pueda acceder al eventElement. Intenta dejarlo después de cerrar el const eventElement= (....) y me cuentas

Comment: está justo después de cerrar event element amigo

Comment: ahora el problema es que al dejarlo fuera de eventelement se pierde el accesso a market element

Comment: no obstante, el map() debería funcionar, simplemente lo que apsa es que no se porque no se evidencia la data en el servidor, porqué segun el console.log estamos accediendo a la data de manera precisa y correcta, no me había pasado, estoy usando tailwind

Comment: No creo que tailwind sea un problema en este caso